# Why are there no statistics on how many ships were sunk by carriers in Ww2?

Tags: world-war-two

This is something that always puzzled me. There seems to be major gaps in historical data, in facts that should be easy to compile. If we know all the Japanese destroyer losses we should know how many were sunk by carrier aircraft versus something else. Yet this information doesn't exist.

Comment: Does the information not exist at all or is it simply that no one has spent the time to turn the raw data into meaningful information?

Comment: Given the confusion of battle, it can be very hard to determine such things. Many ships were damaged by carrier aircraft for example only to sink on the way home from the battle, or decommissioned as beyond repair after making it home. Many ships were also claimed damaged or sunk by multiple pilots/crews. And furthermore, it wasn't really needed to keep exact track of such things, as long as the enemy was sufficiently weakened to vacate the theater of operations.

Comment: What [preliminary research](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786) have you done?

Comment: @jwenting - Yes, in fact it was quite common for ships to be crippled by carrier-based aircraft, and then finished off by enemy surface ships or subs. This is what happened to the US carriers Hornet and Yorktown and the Japanese carrier Chiyoda

Comment: @T.E.D. correct, or by their own side to prevent them falling into enemy hands as well.

Comment: @jwenting - Right. That's actually more typical. However in that case I think it would be reasonable to give a "kill" to the carrier. However, if it got crippled but seemed salvageable, then got finished off by enemy fire, who do you credit?

Comment: @T.E.D. of course, point is however that you'd likely never know it was actually sunk, especially if the hulk was given up several days later while under tow, which wasn't atypical.

Comment: Well, in the case of USS Yorktown, the USN was confident that if they could get her to Pearl Harbor she would eventually be completely repaired in a West Coast yard, such as Bremerton.  Once torpedoed by the Japanese submarine, that was the end, so credit for the sinking goes to the submarine.

Comment: @RLeonard - If forced to decide, I'd probably have to agree with you. However, that sub would never have been able to do that on its own without a lot of hard work (at great cost) by the doomed Japanese carrier crews, so it seems like a final harsh insult to them to take their kill.

Comment: @T.E.D. - True, true.  A culmination of events.  Had the Hiryu VT had not done their job, the submarine would probably never had a chance to work its mischief.  My father, XO of VF-3 at Midway and who shot down one of those incoming VT before it could drop & shared another with a destroyer, always looked on the inability to completely protect Yorktown as the great failure in his 33 year naval service.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of places where one can dive into that sort of information.  First there is the Japanese Monograph # 116 "**The Imperial Japanese Navy in World War II – A Graphic Presentation of the Japanese Naval Organization and List of Combatant and Non-Combatant Vessels Lost or Damaged in the War**,” produced in 1951.  One version of this document can be found [here](https://ww2db.com/other.php?other_id=15).   The lists of vessels . . . [combatant vessels here](https://ww2db.com/ijn/10a.pdf) and [non-combatant vessels here](https://ww2db.com/ijn/10b.pdf) provides information on the source of loss or damage from Japanese records.  Unfortunately, unless you’ve a handle on carrier operations, the notation that this or that vessel was sunk by aircraft can be a little vague.

The other good source for this information is the “**Japanese Naval and Merchant Shipping Losses During World War II by All Causes**” prepared by the Joint Army-Navy Assessment Committee circa 1947.  This document can be found in a couple of places, for example, [here](https://www.history.navy.mil/research/library/online-reading-room/title-list-alphabetically/j/japanese-naval-merchant-shipping-losses-wwii.html) or from [here](https://www.ibiblio.org/hyperwar/Japan/IJN/JANAC-Losses/).  This document is a little more forthcoming on “aircraft” usually noting where such were carrier based.  Again, a knowledge of carrier operations, where and when is helpful.  The Naval History Command presentation, with a little effort and thought, can be easily copied/pasted to spread sheets for data manipulation.  Using something like that, you can get about 520 or so, naval and merchant, and another 50 or so in combination with surface vessels or land based aircraft.

Atlantic/German Navy sinkings by US carrier planes could probably be counted using both your hands and one of a friend's by tracing the various CVE cruises and operations by USS Ranger off north Africa and Norway.

Most of what you find in the JANAC report concerns vessels of 500 tons or more.  Luggers, fishing boats, sampans, barges, etc are not listed.  One finds such things in the Aircraft Action (ACA) reports where they are simply noted as, for example, ". . . and two luggers off point XYZ".  When you ask about "ships" the USN made only specific note of vessels estimated as being 500 tons or more. The hard part in using ACAs for this type of information is that non-combatant types are rarely named but are referred to by classification, e.g., "Sugar-Baker-Charlie" or "Fox-Tare", etc which refer to the general construction type/profile.  Warships were a different matter and were generally identifiable by name or class.

Answer (score -1):

Since you're asking why, I'll give the explanation that will correlate with the answer of R Leonard:

When an air attack occurred in WW2, battle damage assessment was difficult: often, the attacker would send recon aircraft but he would not have total air domination and his recon aircraft could be prevented from achieving his duty correctly.

The result: most of the time pilot reports were the only available information and they were wrong, too exagerated.

When you're someone looking for information, it could be difficult to search for battle reports, that could be still classified. But it is way more easy to look after the losses, and why they were losses. This is also far more accurate since, if a ship is sunk, the navy has interest in recording it.

So, in order to find the information you search for, you'd rather to look for losses record and the reason they were lost. The only problem is that you could miss some damages inflicted to a ship by aircrafts if the ship is ultimately scuttled.